# Maximizing linear functional. When is the maximum unique

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let $F$ be a linear functional over some convex, compact, and closed set $S$ subset of a vector space $X$.

Suppose we want to solve: 
\begin{align}
\max_{x \in S} F(x)
\end{align}

I know that the maximum occurs at one of the extreme points of set $S$.

**My question:**

1. Under what condition can we claim that the maximum is unique?
2. Is it true that the maximum is unique if and only if $F(x)$ is non-constant?
3. Are extreme points the only maximizers (if it is not constant)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the maximum occurs at only one of the extreme points.
2. No.  Consider a triangle in the plane with vertices $[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]$ and $F([x,y]) = x$.
3. No.  Convex combinations of maximizers are also maximizers.

Comment: Is there a way of checking if the maximum occurs at only one of the extreme points?

Comment: Linear programming (if $S$ is a polytope).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a non-unique maximum even if $F(x)$ is not constant.  An illustrative example: let $S=[0,1]^2$ and $F(x_1,x_2)=x_1$.  While $F$ is not constant in $S$, it is constant along part of $\partial S$.  This will give you the proper necessary and sufficient condition for uniqueness.

Comment: What do you mean this will give me proper necessary and sufficient condition? You mean this example, will illustrate the what are nec. and suff. conditions for the general case?

Comment: Paul's answer shows, given no extra assumptions on $F$, we must assume that $\partial S$ does not contain an affine section (his example could be adapted to another convex sex to construct a linear functional whose maximum is attained at every such point of that affine piece). This would seem to imply as well that every element of $\partial S$ would have to be an extreme point (this part I can only intuit pictorially in my head). Given this (unproven) claim, it would seem that $F$'s maximum is attained at two distinct points from $\partial S$ if and only if $F$ is constant.